# Adding char with null terminator to string in C

Tags: c, string, null, char, terminator

What happens when in C I do something like:

```
char buf[50]="";
c = fgetc(file);
buf[strlen(buf)] = c+'\0';
buf[0] = '\0';
```

I'm using some this code in a loop and am finding old values in buf
I just want to add c to buf

I am aware that I can do:

```
char s=[5];
s[0]=c;
s[1]='\0';
strcat(buf, s);
```

to add the char to buf, but I was wondering why the code above wasn't working.

Comment: Note that `c+'\0'` is just `c`. It does not write *two* elements to the array.

Comment: `buf[0] = '\0';` reset `buf` to null-string(`""`).

Comment: [sample code](http://ideone.com/qe5ogw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
buf[strlen(buf)] = c+'\0';
```

will result to this:

```
buf[strlen(buf)] = c;
```

meaning that no addition will take place.

Thus, what will happen is:

```
buf[0] = c;
```

since `strlen(buf)` is 0.

---

This:

```
buf[0] = '\0';
```

puts a null terminator right on the start of the string, overriding `c` (which you just assigned to `buf[0]`). As a result it's reseting `buf` to `""`.

Answer (score 3):

Why would it work?

`char buf[50]="";` initializes the first element to `'\0'`, `strlen(buf)` is therefore `0`.
`'\0'` is a fancy way of a saying `0`, so `c+'\0'==c`, so what you're doing is

```
buf[0]=c;
buf[0]=0;
```

which doesn't make any sense.

The compound effect of the last two lines in

```
char buf[50]="";
c = fgetc(file);
buf[strlen(buf)] = c+'\0';
buf[0] = '\0';
```

is a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  buf[strlen(buf)] = c+'\0';
> ```

probably they wanted

```
buf[length_of_the_string_stored_in_the_buf_table] = c;
buf[length_of_the_string_stored_in_the_buf_table + 1] = 0;
```

same removing last char

```
char *delchar(char *s)
{
    int len = strlen(s);
    if (len)
    {
        s[len - 1] = 0;
    }
    return s;
}
```